# Dot matrix printer printing reverse feeding (upward vertically )

Tags: ansi-escape, pos, posprinter

I have TVS Dotmtrix printer 9 pin, using in receipt printing on (paper roll) . with Python 
I want printer moves 4 line upward vertically and start printing when print file send to printer

i used some escape code like "\x1b\x28\x76\2\0\2\4"
and "\x1b\x65\4"

BUT both work first time when printer switch ON and after that start plain print (without moving upward or without pulling paper downward ).

please suggest some working solutions .
I m new in Python , programming

Comment: I'm afraid your question isn't very clear, and I can't find a TVS manual that describes the escape sequences you use (`ESC (` and `ESC e`). But you are going to have to send any escape sequence before *every* file, not just once.

Comment: I m using hex codes , and all are working perfectly , except this one.  i m sending above hex codes in each file when send to print.

Comment: if you  have any idea or solution please suggest . i want when printer start printing file , (1). printer pull down paper approx 1 inch then start print , but it work only after printer switch on , next time printer start printing from same position(without pulling paper down) .... please suggest better working solution , thanks !! :)

Comment: I know you are using hex codes. `\x1b` is `ESC`, `\x28` is `(` and `\x65` is `e`. But these codes are not computing universals, they are specific to a make or sometimes a model of printer. Without a manual or familiarity with that specific printer it is impossible for us to say what might be wrong. Documentation for such control codes is often very badly written and it is likely that you have followed the instructions closely, but that they are misleading. If you are to get specific help I recommend you put the make and model of the printer in the title of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pull page roll downward (reverse print)

This code working well for me both in TVS as well as Epson Dot Matrix Printer

'\x1Bj2'

Some useful codes are given [here](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/epson_printer_codes.html)

I put '\x1Bj2' code at the top of my printing file and then write other texts.

So, when printer start print it first pull paper downward(reverse) one line and then start printing.